# MDI application with JAVA

Tags: java, mdichild, mdiparent

I want to develop MDI application with java to be run on desktop that download jar files (small applications) and each jar is opened in separated panel in the main MDI applications
Is this possible?
Thanks for advance

Comment: What do you mean by "opened"? Are you referring to viewing the classes in the jar, or executing something in the jar? If the latter, are you expecting to execute arbitrary Java applications, or a subset compatible with your shell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this can be done in Swing by using JInternalFrame. An example: http://www.developerfusion.com/article/3798/programming-with-swing/5/

Comment: Fine, but what about open an external jar on main MDI application as a separated frame

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse RCP would be a better solution. Each view would be the child window of the MDI.